# Test whether $f$ is Lebesgue integrable or NOT

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Let , $f[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be defined by $\displaystyle f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}\sin \frac{1}{x} &\text{ if }x\not =0\\0 &\text{ if } x=0\end{cases}$. Show that $f$ is NOT Lebesgue Integrable.

I want to show $\displaystyle \int_0^1|f|=\infty$.

$\displaystyle \int_0^1|f|=\int_1^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\,dx=\lim_n\int_1^{n\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx$

$$=\int_1^{\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx+\lim_n\sum_{k=2}^n\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx.$$
Now put , $x=(k-a)\pi +z$. Also let $\displaystyle A=\int_1^{\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx$. Then , 
$$\int_0^1|f|=A+\lim_n\sum_2^n\int_0^{\pi}\frac{|\sin\{(k-a)\pi+z\}|}{(k-1)\pi+z}\,dz$$
$$\ge A+\lim_n\sum_2^n\int_0^{\pi}\frac{|\sin\{(k-a)\pi+z\}|}{k\pi}\,dz$$
$$=A+\lim_n\sum_2^n\frac{1}{k\pi}\int_0^{\pi}|\sin z|\,dz$$

$$A+\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_n\sum_2^n\frac{2}{k}=\infty.$$Is my proof correct ?

Any other way to this ?

Comment: It is wrong: the function $f$ has support in $[0,1]$, not in all $\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, you are taking an incorrect $f$

Comment: Why $f$ is incorrect ?

Comment: In your "proof" you are taking $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. In the statement is $\frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: No ...I change the limit..

Comment: You have the right idea, but instead of attempting to transform the problem from $[0,1]$ to $[1,\infty)$ as you did (I think incorrectly), you can work with the integral as given. If you want to avoid grunge, simply observe that $|\sin(\theta)| > 1/2$ for 2/3 of every cycle, so the integral is bounded below by $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 2/(3x) dx$.

Comment: Well...My mistake is changing the limit..So how I can prove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text {For } n\in N \text {  let } x(n)=\frac {1}{\pi (2 n+1/4)},\quad y(n)=\frac {1}{\pi (2 n+1/2)}.$$ We have $0<x(n+1)<y(n)<x(n)$.

For $x\in [y(n),x(n)]$ we have $\sin x\geq 1/\sqrt 2$ and $1/x\geq 1/x(n)>n+1$ and therefore $f(x)>(n+1)/\sqrt 2.$

We have $x(n)-y(n)>1/16\pi (n+1)^2.$

Therefore $$\int_0^1 |f(x)|\;dx\geq\sum_{n\in N}\int_{y(n)}^{x(n)} f(x) dx\geq$$ $$\geq \sum_{n\in N}[x(n)-y(n]\;[(n+1)/\sqrt 2]\geq$$ $$\sum_{n\in N}[1/16 \pi (n+1)^2][(n+1)/\sqrt 2]=$$ $$=\sum_{n\in N}\frac {1}{16\pi (n+1)\sqrt 2}=\infty.$$

Comment: I am unable to understand how $\displaystyle \int_0^1|f| \ge \sum_{n\in \mathbb N}\int_{y(n)}^{x(n)}|f|$ ..

Comment: The intervals $J(n)= [y(n),x(n)]$ are pairwise disjoint measurable subsets of $[0,1].$ Let $S(n)=\cup_{j\leq n}J(j).$ Then $S(n)\subset [0,1]$ and  for every $n\in N$ we have $\int_0^1|f|\geq \int_{S(n)}|f|=\sum_{j=1}^n\int_{J(j)}|f|.$